# git merge without merge conflicts from unrelated branch

Tags: git

I have a git repo that got corrupted on my local machine. In an effort to fix my problem, I deleted the git file on my local machine and ran `git init`. I then ran `git commit -m "fixing git"`.
my *fix_git* branch has my latest code and I'd like to pull in my remote and merge this with my `develop` branch. I went ahead and reset up my remote origin. I then tried to pull my develop branch and got the following error

> fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

I then tried the following `git pull origin cleanup --allow-unrelated-histories`
It created to many merge conflicts to be able to go through. Besides, I intend to keep every change I made on my local machine. How would I fix it so my remote has my changes and I maintain my history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitions:

```
(location alpha) is my local repo file path with my .git file that got corrupted
(location beta)  is a new file path
```

Not saying this is the best solution. It took me 4 hours to come to this conclusion.

1. I simply ran a `git clone` to another location (location beta) separate from my local repo (location alpha).
2. Switched to my develop branch in my newly cloned repo in location beta.
3. Deleted all the files except the .git file.
4. I then copied all of my files
   from location alpha to location beta.
5. Ran `git add .` and `git commit -m "solving git problems"`
6. went to my local repo and ran `git pull -f`

Answer (score 0):

I would have done this:

```
git init .
git add .
git commit "what I want as latest"
git remote add some-remote url-to-repo-with-the-project
git fetch some-remote
git reset --soft some-remote/some-branch
# all changes are in index
git commit -m "Latest changes"
```

And that's it.